# Calling this function in Android using Rhino

Tags: android, rhino

I am working on a project where I need to download a javascript and use it to calculate some values. This is already working on iOS so the javascript seems to be just fine.

Here is the stripped down javascript (I have removed the content as I do not own the script):

```
var resultArray = [];

function calculateRemainingAmountForForecastWeeks(numberOfWeeks, weeklyDisposable, easing, safetyZone, safetyZoneEasing, overSpentThisWeek) {
  // Some calculations...
  resultArray[numberOfWeeks] = spentBeyondForecast;
}
```

I am using Rhino and here is what I do:

```
org.mozilla.javascript.Context rhino = org.mozilla.javascript.Context.enter();
rhino.setOptimizationLevel(-1);
try {
  Scriptable scope = rhino.initStandardObjects();
  rhino.evaluateString(scope, WeeklyApplication.getCalculatorJS(), "JavaScript", 0, null);
  Object obj = scope.get("calculateRemainingAmountForForecastWeeks", scope);
  if (obj instanceof Function) {
    Function jsFunction = (Function) obj;
    // Call the function with params
    Object[] params = new Object[]{numberOfWeeks, weeklyDisposable, easing, safetyZone, safetyZoneEasing, overSpentThisWeek};
    Object jsResult = jsFunction.call(rhino, scope, scope, params);
    // Parse the jsResult object to a String
    String result = org.mozilla.javascript.Context.toString(jsResult);
    Log.d(TAG, "SKN-calculate3=" + result);
  }
} finally {
  org.mozilla.javascript.Context.exit();
}
```

I know it is not the most optimized use of scope here, but I just need to get it working first. I keep getting "undefined" in the result String, what am I doing wrong here?

And when I do get this working, how do I then get the values stored in the "resultArray"?

Thank you
Søren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From code that you posted, it looks like function `calculateRemainingAmountForForecastWeeks()` doesn't return anything, so it's ok to get `Undefined` from it.

Getting value from `resultArray` is easy, as it's just a field in your `scope` scriptable object:

```java
Object[] params = new Object[]{numberOfWeeks, weeklyDisposable, easing, safetyZone, safetyZoneEasing, overSpentThisWeek};
// function doesn't return anything
jsFunction.call(rhino, scope, scope, params);
NativeArray resultArray = (NativeArray) scope.get("resultArray", scope);
double result = ((Number) resultArray.get(numberOfWeeks)).getDoubleValue();
Log.d(TAG, "SKN-calculate3=" + result);
```

Note: of course, I don't know what your types are, so probably you'd have to update this snippet to make it work for you.